# C file splitting in Python?

Tags: python, c, string, header, split

I'm working for my thesis on C files. I need to split a C header to manipulate then the singles words composing it. I have to split lines by all these characters:

1. Spaces and tabs
2. New lines `;` or `\n`
3. Single line comments and multiline comments `// /* */`
4. Pointers `*`
5. Array brackets `[]` or `[dimension]`

So, for example, if I have these few lines:

```
/* This is a
   multiline comment.
*/

typedef int rocket;

// This is a single line comment.
typedef double* pi[10];
```

the split function should return a list (or everything else) like this:

```
["/*","This","is","a","\n","multiline","comment.","\n","*/","\n","\n","typedef","int","rocket",";","\n","\n","//","This","is","a","single","line","comment.","\n","typedef","double","*","pi","[10]",";"]
```

And this should be done in Python!

I tried this but my little knowledge regarding regex suggests me I found an horrible solution!! :)

Thanks,
Dario.

Comment: You could get a C syntax parser...

Comment: doesn't that drop comments, empty lines?

Comment: @yi_H: That depends on the parser. I have written a simple C parser (not nearly complete, but good enough for my purposes) in Delphi that keeps the comments and even formats them nicely, at the right spot, in the resulting conversion to Delphi. A *preprocessor*, as comes with most C and C++ compilers, would probably remove the comments.

Comment: You might want to re-formulate your question.  Right now, this sort of sounds like "Plz send teh thesis."

Comment: Ops... I'm so sorry if it sounds like a DoTheWorkForMe question! It's not a request for doing my thesis, instead I intend it like a simple request of solution to this particular problem. I'm the first one that want to do his own job! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have grammar parser that are done for the job you want. You can find a list of them here :
http://wiki.python.org/moin/LanguageParsing
It will make your life easier.

Comment: I finally found a solution using [ModGrammar](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/modgrammar)! Thank you and also to all the people who answered to this question!

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you should consider toying with [pycparser](http://code.google.com/p/pycparser/). (Without knowing what you're actually doing, I can't really say more than that, sorry)

Comment: I will take a look at pycparser, it looks intersting! Thx.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `re.split` to get what you want:

```
c_code = """
/* This is a
   multiline comment.
*/

typedef int rocket;

// This is a single line comment.
typedef double* pi[10];
"""

import re

def split_c(c_code):
    tok_re = r"(\n)|\s|(;|/\*|//|\*/|\*|\[\d*\])"
    return [t for t in re.split(tok_re, c_code) if t]

print split_c(c_code)
```

This produces:

```
['\n', '/*', 'This', 'is', 'a', '\n', 'multiline', 'comment.', '\n', '*/', 
'\n', '\n', 'typedef', 'int', 'rocket', ';', '\n', '\n', 
'//', 'This', 'is', 'a', 'single', 'line', 'comment.', '\n', 
'typedef', 'double', '*', 'pi', '[10]', ';', '\n']
```

Note that as your requirements get more sophisticated (I worry that the [10] example will really need to be more complicated, for example), this technique may need to be completely replaced.

Comment: And fails predictably for `pi[ 10]`. Sure you could fix that as well and then continue until you've covered the whole c-standard (that may even be possible in this case), but really that's what a parser is there for..

Comment: Also just as food for thought, note that `pi[ /* yep that's allowed */ 10]` is perfectly valid C code - have fun with your regular expression to get that right.

Comment: Yes, exactly, this is what I meant about this technique needing to be replaced.

Comment: I should put this another way: @Dario: it is *really really likely* that you need a better way to pull about your C files.

Comment: @Ned: I understood what you're talking about, you mean the Lex/Yacc way. But I use C keywords as input for an automaton, switching through states. And I thought it was simpler use a parser made on my own instead of a parser already existing.

Comment: @Ned Batchelder Sorry didn't parse your last line myself correctly ;) Didn't downvote you though, so get a +1 to cancel that out a bit.

Comment: I've never liked the downvote/upvote scheme on SO. One upvote negates not one downvote, but five.